# Tracking chrome version to 20 when it's 23

Tags: php, regex, browser, user-agent, user-tracking

I'm trying to make a browser tracking for my website, so far it is going good. But when i came to Google Chrome it just say i'm in Chrome 20.x. When i look i'm in Chrome 23.x.

I have IE 8 and the code is as followed:

```
else if (ereg('MSIE ([0-9].[0-9]{1,2})', $HTTP_USER_AGENT, $log_version)) { 
$browser_version = $log_version[1]; 
$browser_name = "IE";
$browser = $browser_name ." ".$browser_version;}
```

And for my Google Chrome tracker:

```
else if (ereg('Chrome ([0-9].[0-9]{1,2})', $HTTP_USER_AGENT, $log_version)) { 
$browser_version = $log_version[1]; 
$browser_name = "Google Chrome";
$browser = $browser_name ." ".$browser_version;}
```

After the code it goes to my MySQL but if you try it you can simply echo the code.

How do I make it track the right browser version, and what is it i did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at my user-agent for Chrome, it is formatted like this: `Chrome/23.0.1271.64`

Hence, you would have to change your Chrome regex from:

`Chrome ([0-9].[0-9]{1,2})`

to

`Chrome/([0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]{1,2})`

[**Example**](http://codepad.org/FKO58bzz)

Comment: It works, and it dosen't make the 23.x it makes it: Google Chrome 23.0. My Chrome is: 23.0.1271.64 like you

Comment: @user1778037: Could you provide an example? If the version is `Chrome/23.0.1271.64`, what should the regex capture exactly?

Comment: It works better than before, so it is the answer, just saying last it did it like 23.x now i makes it 23.0. That is better... :)